# Hibernate having problems connecting to remote SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I have a webpage which connects to a SQL Server 2017 using Hibernate. I've done already many installations of mentioned app both in machines where the server was localhost as well as remotely.

Now I'm facing a situation where Hibernate is failing to stablish the connection with a remote server (showing the stacktrace page after I click the "login" button). I've already checked everything I could and I couldn't find the mistake. And all this is happening while I'm perfectly capable of connecting to that server from the same computer where the website is hosted (using Tomcat) both with Microsoft SQL Server Management as well as a Windows service, which means the remote server is accessible!

It seems to me the problem lies in the only difference I could find between this installation and previous ones: the IP link to the remote server includes an extra parameter, namely **\DB_COMPANY** as follows (from hibernate.cfg):

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://10.150.10.37\DB_COMPANY:1433;databaseName=COMPANY</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">company</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">Company</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
```

I get the impression Hibernate is failing to deal with this extra parameter and as tested with MS SQL Management and the mentioned service, the `\DB_COMPANY` complement is necessary to access the remote server. I tried with different combinations of slashes and always some kind of error appeared. If backslash, it sad `Error calling Driver#connect`; if forward slash, message `The TCP/IP connection to the host 10.150.10.37/DB_COMPANY, port 1433 has failed. Error: "10.150.10.37/DB_COMPANY. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."`

So is this the problem? How could I fix it? And if it's not, what it is? Feel free to ask for any extra information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to find the problem after all. It wasn't int eh `\DB_COMPANY` section, but rather the port. For whatever reason while the Windows Service was able to communicate with that port, the website wasn't.